# Can I use another computer as a pseudo "sound card"?

Tags: windows-7, audio-streaming

I have XBMC set up on a Windows 7 box that runs my whole home theater. The sound is fantastic, and sometimes I'm working on my laptop and would prefer select music there rather than mess around with XBMC searching YouTube which takes a while.

Since I have mixed music sources (Spotify, YouTube, etc), is there any way I can simply stream all audio from my laptop to the HTPC on demand (over the LAN)?

What I'm imagining is that the remote computer would be acting as a pseudo-sound-card. Can that be accomplished? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous approaches, with advantages and disadvantages.

[Stardock Acoustic Bridge](http://www.stardock.com/products/acousticbridge/) is one solution. It costs a little money up front, but is DRM-free and simple to use.

[PulseAudio](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/) is another option, and happens to be free (as in freedom AND price). It is going to be *very* difficult for a non-technical user to successfully compile, configure, and use PulseAudio, but it is very well-designed and flexible.

[GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) is also free as in freedom and price, and the way that you'd send audio between systems is different with gstreamer than with pulseaudio -- you would have to encode, then payload it, then send it over the network using something like RTP. It would have higher latency than the other methods, but probably easier to set up than pulseaudio, since you are basically just running `gst-launch.exe` with the proper pipeline config.

I'm sure there are other solutions but these came to mind first.

Answer (score 1):

Might want to consider using airplay. XBMC should work as an airplay reciever. If you have a mac you can send your audio over to an airplay reciever. I use a program called airserver http://www.airserver.com/

Comment: There seems to be a solution to stream to Airplay for Windows (http://tuneblade.com/). I'll have to check that out, thanks for reminding me, I had forgotten about XBMC supporting airplay!